# passwd -S Alternate authentication scheme in use

Tags: linux, security, passwd, accounts

in RHEL 7.9, I do `passwd -S` on all accounts in `/etc/passwd` as part of checking user accounts.

```
# passwd -S <account name>

root PS 1969-12-30 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
bin LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
daemon LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
adm LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
lp LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
sync LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
shutdown LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
halt LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
mail LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
operator LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
games LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
ftp LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
nobody LK 2019-08-22 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)
systemd-network LK 2021-06-10 -1 -1 -1 -1 (Password locked.)
dbus LK 2021-06-10 -1 -1 -1 -1 (Password locked.)
polkitd LK 2021-06-10 -1 -1 -1 -1 (Password locked.)
libstoragemgmt LK 2021-06-10 -1 -1 -1 -1 (Password locked.)

ron PS 2021-09-06 1 90 14 5 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
```

This is a clean install of RHEL 7.9 x86-64 from dvd.  Above is an excerpt from doing `passwd -S` on all accounts in `/etc/passwd`.  Can someone enlighten me what `(Alternate authentication scheme in use.)` means and if it would be prudent to perform some kind of `passwd` or `chage` command (and if so what) on those accounts?

Basically I am anticipating during an audit the *show me how you secure and manage user accounts* question so I explain *I do passwd -S on all accounts in /etc/passwd* but how do I explain away the *Alternate authentication scheme in use*?

fwiw, I am doing `chage -m 1 -M 90 -W 14 -I 5` on all my regular user accounts.

Comment: I think that's reporting for the accounts which are disabled accounts (having `*` in the second field in the `/etc/passwd` file) like accounts shutdown, halt, nobody and others.

Comment: In addition to what the other commenter said, this is partially covered in `man 5 shadow`. I can't find anything to back it up, but it seems the default way to disable daemon users (vs. !)